# Как выровнять нумерованный список по центру?

Tags: css3, html5, веб-программирование

Не получается выровнять пронумерованный список по центру. Пыталась заключить в дивы, просто выравнивала элементы списка - либо пропадает нумерация, либо все на странице съезжает незнамо куда. Не могу найти, как же всё - таки выровнять, помогите.

```html
<ol>
  <li> МАТЕМАТИКА</li>
  <li> ИНФОРМАТИКА И ИКТ</li>
  <li> РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: обернуть его блочным тегом, и написать этому тегу text-align: center; а ol display: inline-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.test{
width: 100%;
text-align:  center;
}
.center{
display: inline-block}
li{
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<ol class="center">
  <li> МАТЕМАТИКА</li>
  <li> ИНФОРМАТИКА И ИКТ</li>
  <li> РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: добавь для li text-align: left

Comment: @user355827  Спасибо большое, помогло!!! Люблю

Comment: @MaximLensky поправил,спасибо за замечание

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо! <3

Answer (score 1):

Следует использовать свойство CSS `list-style-position: inside`

Свойство `list-style-position` устанавливает будет ли появляться маркер внутри пунктов списка или снаружи перед началом каждого пункта. Значение по умолчанию — `outside`, которое заставляет маркеры находится снаружи пунктов списка и не позволяет ему центрироваться вместе с содержимым.

Таким образом ваш код будет:

```css
ol {
  /*Устанавливаем маркер/номер внутри пункта списка*/
  list-style-position: inside;
  /*Центрируем*/      
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>МАТЕМАТИКА</li>
  <li>ИНФОРМАТИКА И ИКТ</li>
  <li>РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК</li>
</ol>
```